# Change nested object with one function in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this kind of object where I want to change the Ethereum value for example;

```
const [reportData, setReportData] = useState({
  nameOrganization: "test5",
  socialMedia: "test",
  country: "aa",
  discord: "test",
  date: "date",
  time: "time",
  NFT: {
    ethereum: true,
    tezos: false,
    solana: false,
    other: "test",
  },
});

const changeData = (event: { target: { id: any, value: any } }) => {
  const { id, value } = event.target;
  setReportData({ ...reportData, [id]: value });
};
```

Can somebody help me to change the function in that way so I can change the Ethereum to.

This function works for country, date, or time.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Probably you missed `NFT` key in your setState call:

`setReportData({ ...reportData, NFT: {...reportData.NFT, [id]: value}  });`

Comment: It's a bit messy, though, so I would suggest using [Immer](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/).

Comment: @Alex, does this work if I want to change then socialMedia for example

Comment: No, you should create additional handler for setting NFT inner parts. BTW having complex object structure in the local state is not recommended by React, better to split them to primitive values/simple objects, or use `useReducer` hook instead of common `useState`.

Answer (score 1):

Try spread NFT as well.  (on side note, Actually React does not recommend have complex object as state variable, prefer reducer)

```
const changeData = (event: { target: { id: any, value: any } }) => {
  const { id, value } = event.target;
  setReportData({ ...reportData, NFT: { ...reportData.NFT, [id]: value } });
};
```